# How to show installed applications when opening Unity

Tags: 16.04, unity

I have Ubuntu 16.04.

At first I could see the applications I installed in Unity going to Applications.

Now if I search for a specific application then Unity finds it correctly; however I cannot see here in Unity all the applications I installed and going to Applications it just shows things such as: Banshee, Calculator, COLOURLovers and so on but I cannot see my applications such as Skype, Eclipse, VLC and so on.

Why is it not showing them?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In the Apps lens it shows "recently used" and then installed. If you expand the "installed" you will see all.

Comment: No it does not. It just show the dush plugins nothing else.

Comment: So now *Banshee, Calculator*, etc. are gone too? Perhaps better to edit your question and add a screenshot to illustrate what you're reporting.

Comment: What method did you use to install Eclipse?

Comment: @L.D.James I downloaded the package, extracted it and run it. At first I did not use sudo so it did not appear in the installed applications. After some messing around I reinstalled it using sudo and finally it appeared in the installed applications.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I did it. I took me sometime to find out how to take a screenshot with a mac keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am not yet allowed to comment. When you say you're a new user to ubuntu I would suspect that you have used windows before. I understand your question that you are missing the ordered list of all applications on the computer as e.g. in windows start menus. 
I am using unity desktop and I am missing that too. I am not very happy to search every time I want to open a tool and never did use that feature on windows either. So I just put all Icons I regulary use either in the dock or put it on the desktop with works find. The only list of all application in the GUI is in the software / installed. But I do not find it very useful once there a more programs installed.

Maybe you should have a look at the other desktops provided by ubunut. For example I have been using the Xubunut desktop on two PCs. There is a start menu like thing. What I even like better is the right button context menu on the desktop. I can open a terminal where ever I point to and I can access a structured list with all applications installed (additionally to the start desktop). Its a little bit less stylish than unity, but not a lot. It has not doc, though. 
I do not know the other variants, but I am sure its worth to take a look. You can install them all in parallel an switch the from the log in window. Just uninstall those which you do not like.

Answer (score -1):

A program downloaded and run will not appear in the Ubuntu menu.  The items you install using the **Software Center**, the commandline of **apt install**, and many packages distributed as **.deb** installers.

Some programs may include a routine to create and install a menu item as part of the installer.  But the case of opening and package and running it, you won't find it in the menus.  You could alternatively manually create a launcher and add it to the the applications menu.

If you downloaded **Eclipse** from the official site, you most likely have a later version than the one from the repository (using `apt install`).  You can add your downloaded version to the launcher using these steps:

**Create a launcher:**

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-panel
$ gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

For the new launcher use:

```
Type       Application
Name       Eclipse
Command    (Click the browse button. Browse to the the file to run eclipse.)
Commen     Eclipse programming Development IDE
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Now copy or move the new launcher from your `~/Desktop` to `~/.local/share/applicatons/`

Now you can launch That version of Eclipse from the Ubuntu Dash Search button.